# How to share a link in an Instagram story using instagram-private-api in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, instagram, instagram-api

I'm currently using the instagram-private-api library with Node.js v19 to publish a story on Instagram. I want to include a link in my story, but I can't find any documentation or examples that explain how to achieve this.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
await client.publish.story({
video: videoBuffer,
caption: caption,
coverImage: imageBuffer
});
```

How can I add a link to the above story? Any help or reference would be greatly appreciated.